# Java : Connecting to Redis cluster running in minikube

Tags: docker, redis, kubernetes, docker-machine, minikube

I have a Redis cluster with 3 master and 3 slaves running in minikube.

```
PS D:\redis\main\kubernetes-redis-cluster> kubectl exec -ti redis-1-2723908297-prjq5 -- /bin/bash
root@redis-1:/data# redis-cli -p 7000 -c
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster info
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:6
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:6
cluster_my_epoch:2
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:9131
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:9204
cluster_stats_messages_meet_sent:3
cluster_stats_messages_sent:18338
cluster_stats_messages_ping_received:9202
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:9134
cluster_stats_messages_meet_received:2
cluster_stats_messages_received:18338



127.0.0.1:7000> cluster nodes
de9a4780d93cb7eab8b77abdaaa96a081adcace3 172.17.0.7:7000@17000 slave ee4deab0525d054202e612b317924156ff587021 0 15099603
02577 4 connected
b3a3c05225e0a7fe8ae683dd4316e724e7a7daa6 172.17.0.5:7000@17000 myself,master - 0 1509960301000 2 connected 5461-10922
8bebd48850ec77db322ac51501d59314582865a3 172.17.0.6:7000@17000 master - 0 1509960302000 3 connected 10923-16383
ee4deab0525d054202e612b317924156ff587021 172.17.0.4:7000@17000 master - 0 1509960303479 1 connected 0-5460
28a1c75e9976bc375a13e55160f2aae48defb242 172.17.0.8:7000@17000 slave b3a3c05225e0a7fe8ae683dd4316e724e7a7daa6 0 15099603
02477 5 connected
32e9de12324b8571a6256285682fa066d79161ab 172.17.0.9:7000@17000 slave 8bebd48850ec77db322ac51501d59314582865a3 0 15099603
02000 6 connected
127.0.0.1:7000>
```

I am able to set/fetch key/values via redis-cli without any issue.
Now I am trying to connect to redis cluster from a simple java program running from eclipse.

I understand that I need to forward the port. I executed below command.

```
kubectl port-forward redis-0-334270214-fd4k0 7000:7000
```

Now when I execute below program.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    config.setMaxTotal(500);
    config.setMaxIdle(500);
    config.setMaxWaitMillis(60000);
    config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    config.setMaxWaitMillis(20000);

    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
    jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("192.168.99.100", 31695));

    JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode, config);

    jc.set("prime", "1 is primeee");
    String keyVal = jc.get("prime");
    System.out.println(keyVal);
    }
}
```

Then I get below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:66)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.set(JedisCluster.java:103)
    at com.redis.main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:819)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
    ... 17 more
```

Redis services are created and running as well..

```
PS C:\Users\rootmn> kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP                          11h
redis-0      10.0.0.105   <pending>     7000:31695/TCP,17000:31596/TCP   10h
redis-1      10.0.0.7     <pending>     7000:30759/TCP,17000:30646/TCP   10h
redis-2      10.0.0.167   <pending>     7000:32591/TCP,17000:30253/TCP   10h
redis-3      10.0.0.206   <pending>     7000:31644/TCP,17000:31798/TCP   10h
redis-4      10.0.0.244   <pending>     7000:30186/TCP,17000:32701/TCP   10h
redis-5      10.0.0.35    <pending>     7000:30628/TCP,17000:32396/TCP   10h
```

Telnet to redis ip port works fine.
Am I doing something wrong here. What would cause this issue ?

Comment: Did you create the redis service in your cluster?

Comment: yes redis-service is there.. let me update redis-service logs as well..

Comment: @sfgroups  I have updated. Kindly check if this is how it should be

Comment: based on the example your trying to connect from your desktop right ? or your connecting with-in container running in  minikube?

Comment: @sfgroups I am trying to connect from Desktop. Minikube is running on Virtual Machine on the same laptop.

Comment: I think you need to define the NodePort service type to access from your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the service with type Nodeport. from the below yaml file update the `selection` section to match your redis pod label.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-master-nodeport
  labels:
    app: redis   
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 7000   
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
  type: NodePort
```

Create the service `kubectl.exe create -f redis-master-service.yaml`

then check the service it will give you the port number.
eg.

```
kubectl.exe get svc redis-master-nodep
NAME                 CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
redis-master-nodep   10.0.0.62    <nodes>       6379:30277/TCP   16s
```

Now using minkikube ip:30277 port you can connect to redis.

Hope this helps

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-0
  labels:
    app: redis
    node: node0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: port-7000
    port: 7000
  - name: port-17000
    port: 17000
  selector:
    app: redis
    node: node0

Comment: I have type as LoadBalancer instead of NodePort..can this be causing the issue ?

Comment: It works fine from inside the docker .. I made simple java based application was able to set/get key/value from docker cluster...

Comment: yeah, it will work inside, to access outside we need to define the service type as NodePort.